# How do I assign a HTML title to different pages?

Tags: php, html, title

I am developing a website with oure PHP and HTML on an Apache server. No CMS.

All of my website's pages from the main directory and its subdirectories call one `header.php` file.

I have now run into an issue with all of the page `<title>`'s, as these are obviously defined in the header, so now I don't know how to set a different title for each page.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `$header = 'blah blahblah'; include('header.php')`, then have `echo isset($header) ? $header : 'default header here';` or whatever in the header file.

Comment: Hello Mark, sorry could you break that down so I can understand it please?

Comment: that's literally all there is.

Comment: Yeah but where do these snippets go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is have the title tag like this:

```
<title><? echo $titleIs ?></title>
```

Then, on each page, before the header include, set the title:

```
<? $titleIs='Page Title' ?>
```

Comment: You might want to encapsulate the echo within an if statement, as I did in my answer, to provide a default title in the case of it not being set and therefore throwing out an error.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to have a variable that you set on the main page, before you include the header.php file, and then in the header.php file, use that title.

*page.php*

```
<?php

$title = "My Title";
include "header.php";
```

*header.php*

```
<title>

    // Default Title will be set if you forget to set the $title variable in page.php
    <?php echo isset($title) ? $title : "Default Title"; ?>

</title>
```

Comment: I'll give you a plus one for the idea of adding the default.